# Rails app didn't see ruby version that was chosen by rbenv(Mac OS 10.9.5).

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rbenv

I installed Homebrew, and after that installed Rbenv control ruby versions. Like in this site: [http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/15/using-rbenv-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-ruby/#install-ruby-200---mac-os-x.](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/15/using-rbenv-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-ruby/#install-ruby-200---mac-os-x) 
And installed needed ruby version(1.9.3p547), and set as global. When I type in terminal ruby -v and get:

```
 ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]
```

When I go in Terminal to specific rails project, that I cloned before. And type bundle install and I get:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3
```

And I just was shoked, and think maybe i do something wrong! And type in terminal again ruby -v and get:

```
ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your Gemfile

Comment: What is the output for the following command: `rbenv versions`?

Comment: @BroiSatse It big project and got 60 rows of gems. Ruby specified there is 1.9.3p547.

Comment: @rockskull § system
             * 1.9.3-p547 (set by /Users/sergei/.ruby-version)

Comment: any luck with this problem??? I am also Into this issue.